# ValueError: Unknown loss function: categorical_cross entropy

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I've been working on a project regarding Machine Learning: Classifying Papaya based on its ripeness. But because I'm new in this environment, I've looked up some videos on YouTube about Machine Learning and I've followed this one youtuber. The youtuber didn't have trouble with the code but I had. I followed and did what he was doing. I've looked online about the problem but still didnt get the answers.

The code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.utils import img_to_array, load_img
import numpy as np
import cv2
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


train_path = "D:/DATASETS/Red Lady/Train/"
test_path = "D:/DATASETS/Red Lady/Test/"

BatchSize = 64  # reduce the value if you have less Gpu memory

#img = load_img(train_path + "Class A/2.jpg")
#plt.imshow(img)
#plt.show()

#imgA = img_to_array(img)
#print(imgA.shape)

# Build the model
# ===============

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", input_shape=(100, 100, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(5000, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(131, activation="softmax"))

print(model.summary())

# compile the model
model.compile(loss="categorical_cross entropy", optimizer="SGD", metrics=["accuracy"])

# load the data

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   shear_range=0.3,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   vertical_flip=True,
                                   zoom_range=0.3)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
                                                    target_size=(100, 100),
                                                    batch_size=BatchSize,
                                                    color_mode="rgb",
                                                    class_mode="categorical",
                                                    shuffle=True)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_path,
                                                  target_size=(100, 100),
                                                  batch_size=BatchSize,
                                                  color_mode="rgb",
                                                  class_mode="categorical")

stepsPerEpoch = np.ceil(train_generator.samples / BatchSize)

ValidationSteps = np.ceil(test_generator.samples / BatchSize)

# Early Stopping
# ==============

stop_early = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_accuracy", patience=5)


# train the model
history = model.fit(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=stepsPerEpoch, epochs=50,
                    validation_data=test_generator,
                    validation_steps=ValidationSteps,
                    callbacks=[stop_early])

model.save("C:/Users/MY PC/PycharmProjects/MODEL 1 (Build Model)")
```

**and here are the result and errors:
**

```
C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\python.exe "C:\Users\MY PC\PycharmProjects\MODEL 1 (Build Model)\main.py" 
2024-03-10 18:59:41.733172: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-03-10 18:59:41.835561: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:82] Allocation of 309760000 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
2024-03-10 18:59:42.116138: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:82] Allocation of 309760000 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
2024-03-10 18:59:42.207755: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:82] Allocation of 309760000 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 98, 98, 128)       3584      
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 49, 49, 128)      0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 47, 47, 64)        73792     
                                                                 
 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 45, 45, 32)        18464     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 22, 22, 32)       0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 22, 22, 32)        0         
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 15488)             0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 5000)              77445000  
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 1000)              5001000   
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 131)               131131    
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 82,672,971
Trainable params: 82,672,971
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
Found 2500 images belonging to 3 classes.
Found 652 images belonging to 3 classes.
Epoch 1/50
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MY PC\PycharmProjects\MODEL 1 (Build Model)\main.py", line 85, in <module>
    callbacks=[stop_early])
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\MYPC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_fileuv05hknk.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1146, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1135, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 994, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1053, in compute_loss
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 240, in __call__
        self.build(y_pred)
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 183, in build
        self._get_loss_object, self._losses
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 353, in _get_loss_object
        loss = losses_mod.get(loss)
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 2649, in get
        return deserialize(identifier)
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 2607, in deserialize
        printable_module_name="loss function",
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 770, in deserialize_keras_object
        f"Unknown {printable_module_name}: {object_name}. Please "

    ValueError: Unknown loss function: categorical_cross entropy. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

--version-- Tensorflow = 2.11.0 Keras = 2.10.0 Python = 3.7.16

Comment: You have a **typo**: the loss name is `categorical_crossentropy`, **not** `categorical_cross entropy` ([docs](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#categoricalcrossentropy-class)).

Answer (score 1):

Although the loss function can be passed as a string in the model.compile() method I think you spelled it wrong. Try passing it like this:

```
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),...
```

Comment: Παναγιώτη, please do not answer questions that are essential due to typos; flag the question for closure as such instead.

Comment: *essentially (not "essential")